# How do I delete elements from core data?

Tags: swift, core-data

I am implementing a delete button that deletes the terms and definitions from core data. The implementation I have tried hasn't worked.
What is wrong with my `deletePressed` function and how can I make it work correctly?

```
@IBAction func deletePressed(_ sender: Any) {
  do {
    fetched = try context.fetch(Card.fetchRequest())
    for object in fetched {
      context.delete(object)
    }
  } catch {
    print("you done messed up")
  }
  ad.saveContext()
  fetchData()
}

func fetchData() {
  do {
    fetched = try context.fetch(Card.fetchRequest())
    for each in fetched {
      termLabel.text = each.term!
      definitionLabel.text = each.definition!
      fetchedTerm.append(each.term!)
      fetchedDefinition.append(each.definition!)
    }
  } catch {
    print("")
  }
  termIterator = fetchedTerm.makeIterator()
  definitionIterator = fetchedDefinition.makeIterator()
}
```

This function is supposed to delete the terms and definitions when pressed, but it does not delete the terms or definitions in core data. 
`context.delete(object)` should delete both of them, but for some reason it is not working.
Any chance you know what's wrong with it?

Comment: In what way has it not worked? What happened or did not happen that was unexpected?

Comment: I improved the code formatting and some spelling and also included additional information from a comment.

Comment: well thanks i guess

Comment: What is the delete rule you are using on your relationship between your `Card` entity and your `Term` entity? In order for the term to be automatically deleted you need to set the rule to 'Cascade'.

Comment: the issue was i wasn't casting (object as NSManagedObject) in the context.delete()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was i wasn't casting `(object as NSManagedObject)` in the `context.delete()` function.